# metrics for feature detection/extraction methods

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I wonder how do we evaluate feature detection/extraction methods (SIFT,SURF,MSER...) for object detection and tracking like pedestrians, lane vehicles etc.. Are there standard metrics for comparison? I have read blogs like http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/07/comparison-of-the-opencvs-feature-detection-algorithms-ii/ some research papers like [this](http://epubs.surrey.ac.uk/726872/1/Tuytelaars-FGV-2008.pdf). The problem is the more I learn the more I am confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very hard to estimate feature detectors *per se*, because features are only computation artifacts and not things that you are actually searching in images. Feature detectors do not make sense outside their intended context, which is *affine-invariant image part matching* for the descriptors that you have mentioned.

The very first usage of SIFT, SURF, MSER was multi-view reconstruction and automatic 3D reconstruction pipe-lines. Thus, these features are usually assessed from the quality of the 3D reconstrucution or image part matching that they provide. Roughly speaking, you have a pair of images that are related by a known transform (an affinity or an homography) and you measure the difference between the estimated homography (from the feature detector) and the real one.
This is also the method used in the blog post that you quote by the way.

In order to assess the practical interest of a detector (and not only its precision in an ideal multi-view pipe-line) some additional measurements of *stability* (under geometric and photometric changes) were added: does the number of detected features vary, does the quality of the estimated homography vary, etc.

Accidentally, it happens that these detectors may also work (also it was not their design purpose) for object detection and track (in tracking-by-detection cases). In this case, their performance is classically evaluated from more-or-less standardized image datasets, and typically expressed in terms of precision (probability of good answer, linked to the false alarm rate) and recall (probability of finding an object when it is present). You can read for example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) on this topic.

**Addendum: What exactly do I mean by accidentally?**

Well, as written above, SIFT and the like were designed to match *planar* and *textured* image parts. This is why you always see example with similar images from a [dataset of graffiti](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/mikolajczyk/Database/index.html).

Their extension to detection and tracking was then developed in two different ways:

- While doing multiview matching (with a spherical rig), Furukawa and Ponce built some kind of 3D locally-planar object model, that they applied then to [object detection](http://www.di.ens.fr/willow/pdfs/ijcv06b.pdf) in presence of severe occlusions. This worlk exploits the fact that an interesting object is often locally planar and textured;
- Other people developed a less original (but still efficient in good conditions) approach by considering that they had a query image of the object to track. Individual frame detections are then performed by matching (using SIFT, etc.) the template image with the current frame. This exploits the fact that there are few false matchings with SIFT, that objects are usually observed in a distance (hence are usually almost planar in images) and that they are textured. See for example [this paper](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~nardi/Didattica/SAI/matdid/tracking/SIFT.pdf).

Comment: good answer and maybe something to add: Isn't object-tracking a straight-forward application of transformation computation (after matching) for a subset of all features?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Object tracking (in the Academia world at least) is now implied as a more complex problem that involves a tracking (closed) loop: tracking = predict --> detect (synonym of measure in image) --> correct prediction --> next frame (and start again at the predict step). Computing a transform form features is a way to implement step 2 (measure), but not the whole loop.

Comment: you mean detection as some kind of likelihood computation in probabilistic tracking? That's not tracking-by-detection in my understanding, but it fits your "accidental applications" of feature extraction, so it's ok.

Comment: Hi Micka, it's a bit off topic, but just to clarify: what I call "tracking-by-detect" is that you have some template/model, and you look for that object in each incoming frame without considering temporal consistency (each frame is a new problem). This matches the definition of object detection used in PASCAL challenges and the like. When you talk to someone from the academic tracking field, then tracking involves feedback loops and temporal constraints. Probabilistic tracking is clearly one example approach to tackle this problem.

Comment: ok, that's exactly my understanding of tracking-by-detection. Sorry, now that I read your answer again I completely understand what you meant. 
So SIFT/SURF/etc can be used in tracking-by-detection (accidental use) and the third tracking mechanism (next to t-b-detection and probabilistic tracking) tracking-by-matching (straight forward use). Or in general: SIFT/SURF/etc can be "abused" for object detection or be used straight forward for matching.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've added references in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I gave SIFT, SURF, MSER as an example..there may be better descriptors/extractors for the scenarios i described. Maybe region based descriptors? As far as i know, there are widely used techniques like Hog for padestrian detection, or PCA for vehicle detection. However, I am more interested in doing these thing with feature extraction methods. Also, time spent for implementation is also very crucial. There should be available functions in opencv, which i will use for implementation.